# OpenCV + FFmpeg: Error when recording lossless video

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to record a lossless video from a webcam using opencv.
I would like to use the FFV1 codec for this.

I open my video writter like this:

```
theVideoWriter.open(filename,CV_FOURCC('F','F','V','1'), 30, cv::Size(1280,720), true);
```

I can successfully open the video writter but while recording I get following error message:

> [ffv1 @ 26d78020] Provided packet is too small, needs to be 8310784

The resulting video is not playable. Other FFmpeg codecs like FMP4 work fine.

What does that error mean and how can I fix it?